# process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd() does not get the total StandardOutput

Tags: c#, visual-studio, cppcheck

I have a C# application, which accesses the command line tool "cppcheck" and is then supposed to save the output of this command line tool to the variable "output".

Here is the code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();

startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "/C cppcheck" + " \"" + currentEvent.currentEventFilePath + "\"";

startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();


//the following line is the problem. Output of cppcheck is not completely read:
 string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
 process.WaitForExit();
```

The problem is that the function ReadToEnd() does in fact not appear to read to the end ... instead it stops before the important part that I need.

Here is the total output of cppcheck:
[image]

But only the upper part of this text gets saved into variable "output", namely this part:

[image]

How can I catch the whole output of cppcheck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should also hook into [Process.StandardError](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standarderror(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
string error = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. But what about warnings? Would they also be included in  "p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();" ?